# Newbie issue to deal with the file system with NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

That's probably a dummy issue, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Let's say I open a terminal */home/romu/Musique/Alain Bashung/Compilation* folder to run the following command:

```
AtomicParsley "01. J'écume.m4a" --artwork ../../cover.jpg
```

The result is:

```
Started writing to temp file.
Progress: ======================================================> 99% -|
Finished writing to temp file.
```

So it works. Now, as I want to automate a bit this process, I'm writing a NodeJs script, here it is:

```
// ES6 only
'use strict';

// Get rid off the first 2 elements of the arguments array,
// First is the path of the node enfine itself
// second is the path of this script
let args = process.argv.slice(2);

// hard coded, will always be those values
let root = "/home/romu/Musique";
let ci = "../../cover.jpg";
let artist = args[0];
let album = args[1];

// Album path
let tracks_path = `${root}/${artist}/${album}`;

const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
let ap = spawn('pwd', [], { cwd: tracks_path }); 
ap.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`Location: ${data}`);
});

ap = spawn('AtomicParsley', [`"01. J'écume.m4a" --artwork ../../cover.jpg`], { cwd: tracks_path }); 
ap.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`OUT: ${data}`);
});

ap.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`ERR: ${data}`);
});

ap.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`CODE: ${code}`);
});
```

I get the following output:

```
Location: /home/romu/Musique/Alain Bashung/Compilation
ERR: AtomicParsley error: can't open "01. J'écume.m4a" --artwork ../../cover.jpg for reading: No such file or directory
OUT: AP error trying to fopen "01. J'écume.m4a" --artwork ../../cover.jpg: No such file or directory
CODE: 1
```

I don't know what's going on and why it doesn't work. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Is the node process running in the same Compilation directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the arguments as an array and not the full string.

```
ap = spawn('AtomicParsley', ["01. J'écume.m4a", "--artwork","../../cover.jpg"], { cwd: tracks_path });
```

Comment: If you pass the whole argument string node will escape the quotes and will look for a file named "01. J'écume.m4a" and not 01. J'écume.m4a.